# Schema for address in Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql

I have `satffs` and `users` tables in database.

```
// staffs

id Int
role_id Int
name String
```

```
// users

id Int
name String
```

I need to add address for both. (Because I want to allow user to have multiple addresses in future, but may be not for staffs.)

Which one would be better?

**Option 1**: Create dedicated address databases for each `users` and `staffs`.

```
// user_addresses

id Int
user_id <FK> Int
street String
city String
```

```
// staff_addresses

id Int
staff_id <FK> Int
street String
city String
```

**Option 2**: Or create `addresses` table and create 2 more tables with `users`, `staffs` and `addresses` id references.

```
// addresses

id Int
street String
city String
```

```
// user_addresses

id Int
user_id <FK> Int
address_id <FK> Int
```

```
// staff_addresses

id Int
staff_id <FK> Int
address_id <FK> Int
```

Answer (score 3):

From a normalization standpoint, sure, you can pull out addresses into their own table, but I think at this point in your design, it would be a mistake. This really isn't a technical decision.

A list of relationships between a person and many locations without some kind of identifying characteristics (such as home_address, work_address, past_address) would devolve quickly into a meaningless list of everywhere a person has ever been. In fact, there is very little distinguishing your `addresses` table from... just a map of Earth.

As a result, I suspect that **Option 1** is actually your best bet for now, and will be easy to expand over time as you grow functionality.

Answer (score 1):

In my view **Option 1** is better

But I would prefer a different way to store the addresses in this scenario by using single Table without `Foreign Key`

```
create table addresses (
  id int primary key,
  address_type char(1) not null check(address_type in ('u', 's')),
  linked_id int,
  street varchar(100),
  city varchar(100)
);
```

where `u` stands for `User` and `s` stands for `Staff`. Whenever you will join the address with user or staff table, you have to put condition of `address_type`.

```
select t1.*,t2.* from users t1 inner join addresses t2 on t1.id=t2.id and t2.address_type ='u'
```